# In this code while executing a=A() and b=B() what gets passed in obj argument?

Tags: python

```
class A:
    x=1
    def __add__(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj,A):
            return self.x+obj.x
        return "False"

class B(A):
    x=2

a=A()
b=B()
print(a+b)
```

Comment: In the `__add__()` method, the `obj` argument is the `b` instance of class `B`.

Comment: but while executing a=A() what gets passed into obj arguments?

Comment: The `__add__` method is not called in `a = A()`.

Comment: `The __add__ method is not called in a = A()` - so nothing is passed to the `obj` parameter.

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance

Answer (score 0):

The add method takes `self`, the first object in the addition, and another one, `other`.

For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x=x
    def __add__(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj,A):
            return self.x+obj.x
        raise NotImplementedError

a = A(3)
b = A(4)
res = a + b  # this is essentially a.__add__(obj=b) 
             # self is implicitly the object a
# res == 7
```

Comment: how does if isinstance condition gets satisfied as obj is instance of Class B?

Comment: Well since B is a subclass of A, `isinstance` will still return `True`. Take a look at [this great SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)